# Почему программа вылетает из-за ComboBox->clear();?

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

Почему программа начинает вылетать если добавить очистку списка в ComboBox `ComboBox->clear();` ?
Сам код заполнения ComboBox :

```
void  MainWindow::ComboBoxBuilding(int IdLog) {
    QString QueryLog;
    if (IdLog != -1) {
        QueryLog = "SELECT * FROM \"SchemeObservationLog\".log WHERE id ="+QString::number(IdLog);
        EditLogList.append(IdLog);
    } else {
        ComboBoxLog->clear();
        QueryLog = "SELECT * FROM \"SchemeObservationLog\".log";
    }
    Login conn;
    conn.connOpen();
    QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
    if (query->exec(QueryLog)) {
        int ItemComBox = 0;
        while (query->next()) {
            ComboBoxLog->addItem(query->value(1).toString(), QVariant(query->value(0).toInt()));
            ComboBoxLogFilter->addItem(query->value(1).toString(), QVariant(query->value(0).toInt()));
            if (IdLog == query->value(0).toInt()) {
                ComboBoxLog->setCurrentText(query->value(1).toString());
            }
            if (BoolColorCheckBox == true) {
                ComboBoxLog->setItemData( ItemComBox, QColor( query->value(3).toString()), Qt::BackgroundRole );
                ComboBoxLogFilter->setItemData( ItemComBox, QColor( query->value(3).toString()), Qt::BackgroundRole );
            }
            ItemComBox++;
        }
        if (IdLog==-1) {
           ComboBoxLog->setCurrentIndex(IdLog);
        }
        ComboBoxLogFilter->setCurrentIndex(-1);
    } else {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Ошибка базы данных"),query->lastError().text());
    }
    conn.connClose();
    connect(ComboBoxLog, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this, SLOT(ComboBoxLogChange()));
}
```

...

```
void MainWindow::NewLogDialog() {
    LogDialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    LogDialog->show();
    connect( LogDialog,SIGNAL(AddLog_signal(int)), this, SLOT(ComboBoxBuilding(int)));
    connect( LogDialog,SIGNAL(AddLog_signal(int)), LogEditDialog, SLOT(LogComBoxBuilding()));
}

void MainWindow::EditLogDialog() {
    LogEditDialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    LogEditDialog->show();
    //connect( LogEditDialog, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), this, SLOT(ComboBoxBuilding(int)));
}
```

Программа вылетает даже, если очищать ComboBox таким образом: `for(int i = 0; i < ComboBoxLog->count(); i++) ComboBoxLog->removeItem(i);`
Не понятно почему вылетает если очищать список в ComboBox.

Comment: мало кода, или приведите весь или минимальный самодостаточный пример, воспроизводящий проблему. Правда если Вы такой пример напишите то скорее всего и проблему сразу найдёте

Comment: @vegorov Просто вылетает из за очищения ComboBox. Причём когда первый раз проходит код удаления из ComboBox не вылетает, если второй вылетает. С этим примером надо еще базу тащить. Это и так минимальный пример который строит ComboBox.

Comment: И какой стек вызовов при вылете?

Comment: Не предоставили никакой информации об анонимном классе , где вы вызываете странную функцию `removeItem` или `clear`. Нет ни одного предоставления функций заполнения этого класса. Подробнее пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит из-за `connect(ComboBoxLog, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this, SLOT(ComboBoxLogChange()));`
Если отключать сигналы, а потом включать будет работать нормально:

```
...
LogComBox->blockSignals(true);
LogComBox->clear();
...
LogComBox->blockSignals(false);
connect(ComboBoxLog, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this, SLOT(ComboBoxLogChange()));
```